# Change of Background Color Tag Badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

A few days ago I earned my first bronze tag badge on the [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) tag:
[image]

I had to give almost 100 answers to gain the corresponding up-votes. On the chat I was telling that you can earn the informed badge in under 1 minute, but it will take almost 4 to 5 months to earn the bronze tag. Apart from it having no oak leaves/ribbons (plus not being aligned properly), I don't think it stands out as it should be.

Super User (random example) and Stack Overflow have a clear distinction between normal badges and tag badges:
[image]

I'm in favor of having a different background color for tag badges on Web Applications as well.

Comment: +1 We got to reward those people that put in their hard work. 100 upvotes on anything isn't something that is easy to get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

I have updated the visual style for tag badges. the change will be live after the next production build(within 24 hrs).

Comment: That's awesome !! White is, per our Web Apps style, the best choice?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I feel white provides more contrast between the regular badge style. It's the convention I've been using on other SE sites. Webapps.se is one of the earliest launched sites. I was a noob back then so the CSS and styling can definitely need more improvement. In fact, I plan to do more design tweaking on the site in the coming month.

Comment: Can you add the status Jin?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra done.